# How to stop one thread with another python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am creating a game that gives you twenty seconds to enter an input. I have learned that the only way is probably with multi threading and so I learned how to create multiple threads my goal being that one thread could ask for an input and the other could time. The problem I ran into was that one thread can't terminate another and I can't find a way to make the main thread do it either. Is there a way that I just don't know about? I'm pretty new to threads and python itself so if there is an obvious way, I probably don't know it. This is the program so far:

```
import _thread
import time

def askForInput():
   input(">")

def time(time):
   time.sleep(time)
   #terminate first thread

_thread.start_new_thread(print_time,())
_thread.start_new_thread(time,(20))

while 1:
   pass
```

It would also be fine for either the timing thread or the input thread to be the main program too. Also if there is a way to do it without threading, I'm open, that's just the best way I could think of.

Comment: You're looking for asynchronous calls.  There are features in python 3 that support this.  In python 2, the `twisted` library was the most popular for this type of thing.  If you're designing a game, or anything else that has a GUI, `PyQt/Qt` has a lot of support for sending signals and data between threads.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.